# Executing Function with Batch Execute Class

Tags: apex, batch, query

I am attempting to refresh an account list that I utilize within the execute function of a batch class. I am trying to do this by wrapping the query in a function. My purpose in doing this is so I do not have to repeat the query code when it needs to be refreshed, but instead just execute the function.

I have tried public, private, returning and non-returning values. I receive an unexpected token when I try to state public/private and when leaving it as just the function, it's expecting `;` like a variable declaration.  What am I missing here?

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < Customer_Obj__c > custObjList) {

    List < Account > accList = new List < Account > ();
    List < Contact > conList = new List < Contact > ();

    //QUERY SALESFORCE FOR MATCHES
    for (integer i = 0; i < custObjList.size(); i++) {

        List < Contact > relConList = new List < Contact > ();
        List < Account > relAccList = new List < Account > ();

        //FIND RELATED ACCOUNTS
       queryAccountMatches() {
            relAccList = [select Id, Name from Account where Name =: customObjList[i].Custom_Field__c];
       }

        //REFRESH relAccList
        queryAccountMatches();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, you can't put a function in a function. You'll need to move it "outside" of the execute method:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < Customer_Obj__c > custObjList) {

  List < Account > accList = new List < Account > ();
  List < Contact > conList = new List < Contact > ();

  //QUERY SALESFORCE FOR MATCHES
  for (integer i = 0; i < custObjList.size(); i++) {
    List < Contact > relConList = new List < Contact > ();
    //REFRESH relAccList
    List < Account > relAccList = queryAccountMatches( customObjList[i].Custom_Field__c);
  }
}

    //FIND RELATED ACCOUNTS
public static Account[] queryAccountMatches(String param) {
  return [select Id, Name from Account where Name =:param];
}
```

Note: of course, you shouldn't have queries inside of a loop if you can help it, but this answer is directly for the purpose of answering the question.